# How to prevent iTerm2's Hotkey Window from changing desktop?

Tags: macos, iterm

I've configured Hotkey Window to slide down from top when global hotkey is pressed (like console). But when I do that when maximized window is active it switches to a desktop. Is there a way to prevent that? I want terminal to just slide over fullscreen window.

Comment: Some windows like WiFi login or notification windows are displayed over fullscreen apps so it's possible. Looks like such windows are displayed on all desktops and follow user until they are closed. This is what I expect from the quick console window too.

Answer (score 1):

iTerm developers answered that this feature is already in a nightly build

Comment: This answer is not really helpful for future readers.